# input a string then return it compressed(deflated) using zlib.h

Tags: macos, compression, cocos2d-iphone

It sounds easy, but it's giving me a hard time.
I am trying to create a method that inputs a string then return it compressed(deflated) using zlib.h (the one from zlib.net)

I've read the zlib.h a couple times, no success :/

I think I need to use the deflateInit2() function, but woah, look at its complex definition:

```
#define deflateInit2(strm, level, method, windowBits, memLevel, strategy) \
    deflateInit2_((strm),(level),(method),(windowBits),(memLevel),\
                  (strategy),           ZLIB_VERSION, (int)sizeof(z_stream))
```

Anyone could put me on the right track please?

Comment: it's been 1 day, still no hero can save the world!?

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged w/ cocos2d-iphone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103565/how-to-determine-compressed-size-from-zlib-for-gzipped-data